# After installing minGW, gcc command is not recognized

Tags: c, windows, command-line, mingw

I have installed minGW, and I have a file "test.c".

I typed `gcc test.c -o demo` at the command prompt, while in the directory where I saved the "test.c" file. But it didn't work; I got this message:

> gcc is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

How do I make the `gcc` command work on Windows with minGW?

Comment: Check your `$PATH` variable. Is the directory `gcc.exe` is located in included in there? If not, add it. And **do some research first**. I bet there's information on that on the Internet.

Comment: I had PATH set to Java SDK. Now I changed it to MinGW. I can't add two PATH. Is it not possible to use both Java compiler and gcc compiler on the same computer?

Comment: Of course it is. There should be many more paths listed in `$PATH` than just these two. Don't change it but **append a semicolon and behind that the path to the executable**.

Comment: Ok got it. Just need to use ; and add directories to other compilers: C:/compilerA/bin/;C:/compilerB/bin/

Comment: for me I needed to remove the trailing backslash::: `C:\MinGW\bin` worked instead of `C:\MinGW\bin\ `

Comment: A more up to date duplicate: ['gcc' is not recognized - How to make gcc/mingw work in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772964/gcc-is-not-recognized-how-to-make-gcc-mingw-work-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing on `Path Variable` settings. Refer the 'Environment Settings' section on this page :

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: Link is outdated, Mingw is also hard to find. Next time post short description from external page to avoid suchs situations