# codelite scan could not locate mingw any on your machine error

Tags: c++, c, mingw-w64, cppcheck, codelite

I installed mingw and checked it in cmd by writing c++ --version it runs sucessful but whenever i open my codelite it says could not locate any mingw on your machine i have tried reinstalling both mingw and codelite few times nothing works someone please help me

Tried scanning mingw compiler on codelite but it could not locate mingw and it(mingw) is already installed in my machine and running too help me please

Comment: I don't know about your IDE but generally you have to add the installation \bin folder to your path. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772964/gcc-is-not-recognized-how-to-make-gcc-mingw-work-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this IDE but this link is probably what you are looking for.

https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/AddNewCompiler

Since the scan failed you will have to manually add the path to your compiler in codelite. The compiler will most likely be in the mingw folder under the name 'g++.exe'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).